# Got .zip file when I downloaded Facebook iOS SDK. How to install it?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

As mentioned on official website and many other tutorials, downloading Facebook SDK for iOS gives a installation wizard by Facebook which guide us for installing Facebook SDK for iOS on our machine. But, when I downloaded, I got a .zip file and when I double click it, it just extracts. What is the method of installing it for using purpose (As they mentioned that installation wizard will install the SDK in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add that FaceBook framework to your app. To do that follow these steps :

Open ~/Documents/FacebookSDK

1. Drag the FBSDKCoreKit.framework to Frameworks in Project Navigator. Create a new group Frameworks if it does not exist.
2. Choose Create groups for any added folders.
3. Deselect Copy items into destination group's folder. This references the SDK where you installed it rather than copying the SDK into your app. ( It helps when you download new SDK, the older one gets replaced at the same folder). However i'd recommend copying the SDK into your app to maintain your won versions and avoid unnecessary upgrades. Facebook sometimes upgrades very fast.
4. The SDK automatically loads its framework and resource dependencies.

You might want to follow read more about this on FaceBook's Docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)